# Without using minipage, can we resize both input and output boxes of LTXexample?

Tags: showexpl

[image]

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=50mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\SX@codeInput}{xleftmargin=0pt,xrightmargin=0pt}{}
  {\typeout{***Successfully patched \protect\SX@codeInput***}}
  {\typeout{***ERROR! Failed to patch \protect\SX@codeInput***}}
\makeatother
\lstset{%
  literate={ï}{}0
         {»}{}0
         {¿}{}0,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,    
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\sffamily\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{Green}\itshape,                                 
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,                          
    showstringspaces=false,
    backgroundcolor=\color{Yellow!30},
    frame=single,
    framerule=0.4pt,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    framesep=3pt,
    xleftmargin=3.4pt,
    xrightmargin=3.4pt,
    tabsize=2,%
    explpreset={pos=b,language={[LaTeX]TeX}}%
}
\begin{document}

\section{with minipage}
\noindent%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{LTXexample}[pos=b]
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 8}\frac{1}{(x-8)^2}=+\;\rotatebox{90}{$8$}$
\item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 7}\frac{1}{(x-7)^2}=+\;\rotatebox{90}{$7$}$
\item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 6}\frac{1}{(x-6)^2}=+\;\rotatebox{90}{$6$}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{minipage}


\section{without minipage}
\noindent%
\begin{LTXexample}[width=0.5\linewidth,pos=b]
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 8}\frac{1}{(x-8)^2}=+\;\rotatebox{90}{$8$}$
\item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 7}\frac{1}{(x-7)^2}=+\;\rotatebox{90}{$7$}$
\item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 6}\frac{1}{(x-6)^2}=+\;\rotatebox{90}{$6$}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{LTXexample}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key `width` is only responsible for the formatted text, not the source code. To change the width of the typeset source code, modify your second `LTXexample` (without minipage) as follows:

```
\begin{LTXexample}[explpreset={linewidth=0.5\linewidth},width=0.5\linewidth,pos=b]
```

Comment: @lockstep, thank you very much. It works. Excellent! :)

Comment: why do you enclose linewidth=0.5\linewidth by explpreset? without doing that, it still works. I don't know the purpose.

Comment: It might be worth doing a `\newcommand\mywidth{0.5\linewidth}` or soemthing, so that you can change both widths at once...

Comment: @xport: I followed p. 2 of the `showexpl` documentation and p. 33 of the `listings` documentation. Note: What follows `explpreset=` is a key-value-list of its own, possibly with several entries.

Comment: So using explpreset is not a necessity, because I have tried without using it & still works. Thank you.

Comment: @lockstep, I did an experiment. Here the result: explpreset={<key-val options>} can contain options from listings and/or showexpl. It is worth using explpreset whenever we use both lstlisting and LTXexample in the document. By setting some options in explpreset, these settings will be applied to LTXexample only (without affecting lstlising). Options declared in lstset will be applied to both LTXexample and lstlisting, unless they are overriden using their optional arguments. Thank you.